# Does Naive Bayes algorithm classify words or phrases?

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification, naivebayes, textblob

I want to use the Naive Bayes algorithm available on Text blob package in python.
Does it classify "I love terrorism and I hate peace" and "I love peace and hate terrorism" the same way?

Comment: Have you tried to check yourself? This seems amenable to straightforward empirical verification...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

It depends solely on **data representation**. If you use bag-of-words (1-gram) representation, then yes, both documents will be the same. But if you use any n-grams with n>1, they will be different (and separable for NB). Basically nearly any "fancier" approach than simple bag-of-words will make NB distinguish between these two.